# ngGrid not displaying data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I have created a directive to display my grid as the following:

This is the widgets module

```
 (function() {
    angular.module("Widgets", []);
}());
```

This is the application module

```
    (function () {
    var app = angular.module("productManagement",
        ["common.services", "ui.router", "ui.mask", "ui.bootstrap","ngGrid", "Widgets", "productResourceMock"]);
    (function () {
    var app = angular.module("productManagement",
        ["common.services", "ui.router", "ui.mask", "ui.bootstrap",**"ngGrid"**, **"Widgets"**, "productResourceMock"]);
}());
```

This is the controller

```
(function () {
angular.module("productManagement")
    .controller("ProductController",
    ["productResource", "ProductService",
    productListController]);
function productListController(productResource, $scope, productService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.testData = [
        { imageUrl: "test", productName: "test", productCode: "1222", releaseDate: "12", price: "344" },
         { imageUrl: "test", productName: "test", productCode: "1222", releaseDate: "12", price: "344" }
    ];

    vm.columnDefs = [
        { field: 'imageUrl', displayName: 'Image' },
         { field: 'productName', displayName: 'Product Name' },
          { field: 'productCode', displayName: 'Product Code' },
           { field: 'releaseData', displayName: 'Date' },
        { field: 'price', displayName: 'Unit Price' }
    ];

    vm.productList = function () {

    };
    productResource.query(function (data) {
        vm.products = data;
    });

    vm.showImage = false;
    vm.toggleImage = function () {
        vm.showImage = !vm.showImage;
    };

};}());
```

This is the widget directive

```
angular.module('Widgets').directive('gridwidget', function ($compile) {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="options"></div>',
    scope: {},
    compile: function(cElem, cAttrs) {
        return {
            pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                scope.options = {};
                scope.options.columnDefs = scope.$parent.$eval(iAttrs.cols);

                scope.options.data = scope.$parent.$eval(iAttrs.tableData); //iAttrs.tableData;
                //scope[iAttrs.tableData] = scope.$parent.$eval(iAttrs.tableData);

                scope.options.showGroupPanel = true;
                scope.options.showSelectionCheckbox = true;
                scope.options.showColumnMenu = true;
                scope.options.showFilter = true;
                scope.options.enablePaging = true;
                scope.options.showFooter = true;
                console.log(scope.options);
                scope.$parent.$watch(iAttrs.tableData, function(value) {
                    var val = value || null;
                    if (val) {
                        scope[iAttrs.tableData] = scope.$parent.$eval(iAttrs.tableData);
                    }
                });

            }
        };
    }
};});
```

In the index HTML page I have the references to the following:

```
  <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-ui/ui-utils.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/ng-grid.js"></script>
 <script src="app/products/widgetsModule.js"></script>
<script src="app/products/gridWidget.js"></script>
 <script src="app/products/ProductController.js"></script>
```

Product List view displays the grid

```
  <gridwidget table-data="vm.testData" cols="vm.columnDefs"></gridwidget>
```

The issue that I am facing with is that the grid displays on the product List view page, the total Items count displays the correct number of records but no data is displayed on the grid. 
Would anyone know what is the issue here?
Cheers.